How can I process raw text format job posts from LinkedIn or similar sites into a key-value format?
Ive collected some job posts from linked for research purpose. I would like to get specific datas from these job posts and save inside my sql database. So how can I process the job posts txt files and get specific fields such as title, description, skills, requirements list, notes (if there is any), role, location, benefits etc. And also every job posts have their own formats. I guess I would need to use some NLP techniques like NER but im clueless on how to actually approach this. Im not an ML guy so some suggestions, references would be great.
